# How to constraint list of dynamic views

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS development. I have a problem with dynamic creating views. I want to achieve something like image below.

[image]

I want to make view with title labels and list of labels below.

F.e. I have 'hobby list', I want to make every element on this list as UILabel with hobby text, and also make possible wrapping UILabel when there is no place for it in current line.

I know how to achieve wrapping UILabel list. I used this solution: https://iostutorialjunction.com/2017/10/create-tag-clouds-view-in-swift-tutorial.html. But the problem is that constraint top to bottom doesn't work.

```swift
tags.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tags.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
tags.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tags.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tags.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

I'm Android Developer, I achieved this on android without problems, is there any solution for iOS?

Comment: Have you tried embedding the labels in a vertical stack view?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD will it wrap childs to the next line?

Comment: Marek, you can make the labels in the stack view wrap to the next line if you want, or just keep them limited to one line. You don't need to assign constraints/anchors to the labels inside the stack view, just need constraints on the stack view itself.